# Improper Firebase config?

Tags: firebase

Working within React, and trying to configure my Firebase realtime database via the following

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: "",
  };


const fireDb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default fireDb.database().ref();
```

However, I keep receiving the error that `';' is expected` in the terminal, which does not make sense when looking at the config.

Is my config that far off?

Comment: should I not be? Even when removed, the error still remains @th3g3ntl3man

Comment: Try importing `import 'firebase/auth';`